# Slow IO on Windows 7 development VM running on Hyper-V

Tags: visual-studio-2013, io, virtual-machine, windows-7-x64, hyper-v

I am running a complex moderately complex visual studio build which usually takes about 10 minutes to complete on a non-virtualized machine running on decent hardware (8Gb memory,2.7 GHz i7, SSHD). When I run the build on windows 7 guest running on Hyper-V/Server 2012 (on a precision 5810) it takes over an hour to run.  Additionally, the primary bottleneck for most of the build when running the build in a non-virtualized is the cpu.  When running the build in the Windows 7 virtual environment the bottleneck is IO.

I would post pictures of resource monitor, but SO isn't giving me the access to that since this is a brand new account.  Anyways - the cpu and memory for both the guest and host do not indicate that any intensive processing is taking place, however the IO is very high.  The Queue Length is running steady between 10 and 50.  About 3 MB is being read per/second while 8-10 MB is written per second.  Active time of the physical disk is pegged at 100%.

Running a Ram disk drastically reduces the time here (to 6-8 minutes) but isn't practical because I can't afford to dedicate the necessary memory on a regular basis.

Any ideas on why my queue length is so high and/or how to improve performance here?

Answer (score 1):

IO heavy applications/processes always suffer under a VM. For a proper comparison, it would help to know the build time on the host OS to the same physical volume that the guest OS VHD is stored. If the host OS only has a single physical disk you will suffer performance penalties, guest OS volumes should be created on dedicated drives (ie. not the same drive as your programs, operating system, and other files.)

You can try increasing partition/compute times within Hyper-V manager (to give your VM the maximum amount of compute time) but I doubt this will affect IO much.

You can also try using a dedicated physical drive (Fx. an SSD) that is NOT mapped to the host OS (if you try, both Host OS and Guest OS will access volume and eventually corrupt allocation tables.) This may yield some improvement since the storage volume is physical (rather than having the guest OS execute through a virtualization stack that delegates access to a VHD/etc.)

HTH, would be interested to hear your results/findings since we do a fair amount of virtualization in test here and still have not run into this problem.